# Extract first string of each word in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the DF as below

```
col1
GRE MET HOCK 38 
ASS COM CORD EMERG  INIT
```

I would like to create a column with first string of each word from col1 but keeping integer, such as below

```
col1                        col2
GRE MET HOCK 38             GMH38
ASS COM CORD EMERG  INIT    ACCEI
```

I found something that might work, but not giving the expected output

```
import re
input = "GRE MET HOCK 38"
output = "".join(item[0].upper() for item in re.findall("\w+", input))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['GRE MET HOCK 38', 'ASS COM CORD EMERG  INIT']})
df['col'].str.replace(r'\b(?!\d+\b)(\w)\w*|\s+', lambda x: x.group(1).upper() if x.group(1) else '', regex=True)
# => 0    GMH38
#    1    ACCEI
#    Name: col, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tfrqvu/1). Depending on what kind of numbers and what kind of word boundaries you need to support the regex can be adjusted.

The current pattern matches

- `\b(?!\d+\b)(\w)\w*` - a word boundary, and then one word char (captured into Group 1 and then zero or more word chars, but these word chars should not constitute a digit sequence as a whole
- `|`  - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

If Group 1 matches, this uppercased value is the replacement, else, the match is removed (the replacement is an empty string).

Answer (score 3):

`split` the strings on spaces, then stack into one long Series. Then you can take the first letter, except where the split part of the string `isnumeric`, and finally join the results and assign back, which aligns on the original DataFrame index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['GRE MET HOCK 38', 'ASS COM CORD EMERG  INIT']})

s = df['col1'].str.split('\s+', expand=True).stack()
df['col2'] = s.str[0].mask(s.str.isnumeric(), s).groupby(level=0).agg(''.join)
```

---

```
                       col1   col2
0           GRE MET HOCK 38  GMH38
1  ASS COM CORD EMERG  INIT  ACCEI
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Iterate on column items and extract words with split items by spaces,then create new words with fist letter of words and save the new word to a list,then add this list to a new column of DataFrame

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = {
    'col1' : ['GRE MET HOCK 38', 'ASS COM CORD EMERG INIT'],
}

new_column = []

df = DataFrame(data)

for item in df['col1']:
    new_item = ""
    #extract words from item with split by space
    words = item.split()
    for word in words:
        #add first letter to new item
        new_item += word[0]
    #add new item to new column
    new_column.append(new_item)


#add new column to DataFrame
df['col2'] = new_column
print(df)
```